# Print var value in HTML after submitting a request to any API via NODE JS & express & jquery

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

Need help to do this simple task: HTML AJAX LINK > NODE JS API CALL TO GET VALUE > WAIT > THEN > RETURNING VALUE AND PRINT to HTML or JS or PHP.

The example below give this in HTML after clicking on the link Get My Value:{"myvalue":"testundefined"}.
Server Side console is ok. The API call is ok returning the value to Node server.

As i am new to Node and async i would appreciate any help to solve this. I read many tutorials and examples to get to this point now i am stuck. Thx in advance !

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const API = require("API");
const KEY = new API({ apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" });

function getmyvar(){
var result = callAPI.integer({});
return result; // will return a number
}

const myvaluevar = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve(getmyvar());
    },1000);
});
    
async function getmyvaluevar() {
  const results = await myvaluevar; 
  console.log(results);
  return results;
}


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.sendFile('/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.get('/getmyvaluevar', function(req, res) {
   
   var myvalue = getmyvaluevar().then(
         
          res.send(
   { myvalue: 'test'+ myvalue }
  )
         )
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Node server is running..');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>$('#get-data').on('click', function() {
  $('#myvalue').html(JSON.stringify(json));
});</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="/getmyvaluevar" id="get-data">Get My Value</a>
<div id="myvalue"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I know your question well you should try this:

note: don't use `.then()` and `async await` toghether

```
app.get('/getmyvaluevar', async function(req, res) {
   
   var myvalue = await getmyvaluevar()      
   res.send({ myvalue: 'test'+ myvalue })
});
```

Comment: Thx. Script is now functional without using () after myvaluevar. Node return an error "it's not a function".

Comment: I updated my answer, you don't need to `()` just use async await like above answer @JCDweb

Comment: thx a lot for your help. much appreciated.